# Some Gear Prawn

Tags: gear

Here are some cool photos in a gallery I just stumbled over.

Check 'em out! Thought you all would enjoy seeing some different rigs.

http://gallery.me.com/jwsound#100220&bgcolor=black&view=grid

Comment: Holy crap, there are some great ideas in this gallery of how people are organizing things.  Half of me is happy to to get the ideas but the other half of me is upset because I just figured out how I am going spend a bunch of money.  Now back to work so I can pay for it.

Comment: Yeah! There are some awesome design ideas in there. It's cool to see what other pros have and choose which features you want to have on your own cart or rig. I like the dirtbike and amphibious rigs - haha

Comment: You shouldn't be posting stuff like that on here, a lot of people content with their current gear suddenly get ideas that they can't afford and a lot of partners get very angry:-)

Comment: Drool ………………...

Answer (score 1):

Aaton website also has a lot of images of sound recordist using their Cantar-X recorder.

http://www.aaton.com/gallery/on-location

Some pretty nice rigs in there as well :)

Comment: WuuaaaaahhhH!!!!!  http://www.aaton.com/gallery/on-location/Florian_Kamerer331